# Does Battlefield 4 Premium transfer from xbox360 to xbox1?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, battlefield-4, battlefield-premium

I have BF4 for the xbox 360, and was thinking about getting it/trading it in for the xbox1 version. Does the premium membership transfer between the consoles, and will my stats reset?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [battlefield.com upgrade offer](http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield-4/next-gen-upgrade), Premium membership is transferable and you can transfer your stats as well:

> **When I upgrade platforms, will my stats transfer with me?**
>
> Yes! You will be able to bring your multiplayer progress with you – your rank, score, K/D ratio, wins, time played, service stars, dog tags taken, vehicles destroyed, repairs, revives, squad score, accuracy, and more will transfer from Xbox 360 to Xbox One and PlayStation 3 to PlayStation 4.
>
> **Does my Battlefield 4 Premium membership carry over?**
>
> Battlefield 4 Premium membership from Xbox 360 to Xbox One has been extended and is valid until further notice. The membership transfer from PlayStation 3 to PlayStation 4 owners also remains valid until further notice.

The stats transfer appears to be a [one-time transfer](http://news.xbox.com/2013/08/14/games-battlefield-4-stats/), though:

[image: one time transfer]

Comment: Do you know if I will be able to play with my old XBL friends on the Xbox One using this method?